# Como buscar un userName sin importar si esta con mayuscula o minuscula (Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Como puedo realizar una busqueda de un userName con mongoose sin importar que el userName este con mayusculas o minusculas.

```
User.findOne({userName:userName})
```

Como tengo la consulta, si escribo un userName con mayuscula o minuscula y no coincide con la base de datos no se encuentran coincidencias.

Comment: Como tienes declarado tu esquema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solucion:**

```
User.findOne({userName:{ $regex: userName, $options:'i' } })
```

Comment: Estaba por publicar. Excelente respuesta. Solo toma en cuenta que al usar `findOne` obtendras el primer resultado coincidente, de manera que si puedes repetir el userName con caracteres diferentes como "LEgna" y "Legna" obtendras un resultado diferente de lo que esperas.  Seria bueno asegurarse de que esto no pase en tu schema.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar en tu respuesta el porqué hacerlo de esa forma? Te invito a leer [answer]. Escribir el código como respuesta sin dar una explicación se considera de baja calidad. Saludos